# Can a ruler going very fast bend spacetime?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime

In my physics class we were talking about this hypothetical situation:

There is a gap and a meter stick, when they are at rest in the same frame of reference the meter stick is the same size as the gap. Then, in an alternate situation, the same meter stick is moving very fast in the reference frame of the gap, and the gap sees the meter stick shrink. From the stick's reference frame the gap shrinks. In both frames of reference the stick hits just below the gap (I drew a picture and put it below). But in the reference frame of the stick it's bending to hit that same spot that it hits in the reference frame of the gap (where it doesn't bend).

I know that time and space can change in reference frames, but I was under the impression that this happens to things only along one axis (like the x axis), and the fact that something as solid as a meter stick can be bent without breaking it is very strange to me. This is what makes me think that a warping of space time is involved, but I don't know why this would happen. I heard from a lecture that mass and energy bend space time, is that what's happening here? If so is it the meter stick that is bending it?

Here is my picture of the situation

[image]

Edit: The stick is coming from the left to the right, in the first frame it falls off of the cliff but because it was moving to the right at a fast speed it doesn't stop moving forward as it falls, hence the impact on the cliff.

Comment: This is I think an instance of [the Ladder Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ladder_paradox).

Comment: @StephenG Yes I know about the Ladder Paradox, but I haven't read about the ladder bending if it were to be stopped at the back door of the structure.

Comment: You have not shown the direction of motion of the stick.  Is it along the length axis or different? There is no reason for the stick to bend.

Comment: @BowlOfRed I edited the question, it's going from left to right. In this example the stick *does* bend in the stick's frame of reference, I know it does this I'm just not sure why.

Comment: Just for clarity, I thought I should emphasize that this has nothing to do with bending spacetime (at least not in any way implied in the question). What this does show, as already said, is that there are no rigid objects. Special relativity takes place in flat Minkowski space, so nothing fancy really happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question wasn't clear, but what I think you're saying is that in the barrier's frame, the ruler is moving left to right.  This motion would necessarily miss the gap entirely.

But the ruler (with a length that appears to be smaller than the gap) suddenly accelerates downward into the gap and strikes the wall.  Since it's moving sideways at a significant fraction of $c$, the downward acceleration must be immense!

If so, part of the issue here is that the ruler is not a point object.  How does it accelerate downward?  Let's assume it has rocket engines all along the upper surface that fire simultaneously in this frame of reference.

Well in the ruler's frame of reference, these rockets would not fire simultaneously.  The rockets at the front would fire first.  This would certainly bend (or destroy) the ruler.